# Link outside an image

Tags: jquery, html, image, hyperlink

```
<body>
  <img src="myimage.png">
</body>
```

I would like to have a `<a>` link ONLY when you click OUTSIDE the `<image>`.

The full body should be a clickable link.

How can I do this?

Comment: Unclear what's your asking...

Comment: This is a child page, I would like that if I click outside that image (the image does other things) I go back to parent page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qqjtgz3j/)

```
<body>
  <a href="http://google.co.uk"></a>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/250" />
</body>
```

```
img{
    position:relative;
    z-index:9999;
}

a{
    background:red;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    z-index:10;
}
```

`position:fixed;` means that even when scrolled it will still be anywhere on screen.

Answer (score 0):

Create a link which fills the whole screen:

```
a.myclass {
  display: block; 
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

and position your image absolute, with an higher z-index. Maybe you need to set `pointer-events: none;` on your image tag.